# Can't fill circle background with color threshold

Tags: d3.js, svg, maps

I try to display circles on a map for a particular dataset. The dataset provides where to center the circle. The dataset contains an identifier (attribute `name`), a year (attribute `year`) and a value (attribute `value`)

I would like to display two things at this level:

- The radius of the circle according to the value
- The background color (fill) of the circle according to the year and using threshold
- A tooltip when the circle is clicked.

Here is the code I use:

```
var circle = d3.geo.circle();
var color = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([ 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 2000, 2050 ])
  .range("#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f");

var elements = layerElement.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('id', function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

elements
      .datum(function(d) {
        return circle
           .origin(origin({d: d}))
           .angle(radius({d: d}))();
      })
      .attr('class', 'point')
      .attr('d', path)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.year);
      })
      .style('opacity', '0.6');

elements.on('click', function(d) {
    (...)
});
```

I set an identifier to each circle. I see them within the in-memory SVG DOM:

```
<path id="Hoba"
      class="point" 
      d="M488.55415440889976,286.8579825670507L488.45185788883936,284.8328597859807L488.56757478032006,282.785303550314L488.90003726486356,280.73774731464727L489.445602813917,278.71262453357724L490.1982940971579,276.7321228760774L491.14986447137636,274.8179411327541L492.2898883324236,272.99105147935524L493.6058753403125,271.2714697012249L495.0834072659968,269.6780358961697L496.7062959605052,268.2282080584055L498.45676071568937,266.9378708051187L500.3156230733832,265.82116134127676L502.2625169486039,264.890314569452...L508.2862800372698,302.266499816963L506.206659850514,302.3738076922315L504.15052774957604,302.26649981696306L502.14041114802717,301.9457518786948L500.19833330399786,301.41507805895924L498.3455720287532,300.680292531176L496.6024265625401,299.74944575935126L494.9879951718629,298.63273629550935L493.5199659048794,297.34239904222255L492.2144227974436,295.8925712044583L491.08566965304294,294.2991373994032L490.1460733273343,292.5795556212728L489.4059282342853,290.752665967874L488.8733435584207,288.8384842245506Z"
      style="fill: yellow; opacity: 0.75;">
```

My problems are:

- Within the function `attr`, the first parameter corresponds to the selected shape but there is no identifier in it. Here is the content I get:

  ```
  {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.279833759995999,-21.628058088269754],(...)[5.525725679844768,-22.85403683844725],[5.279833759996005,-21.628058088269807]]]}
  ```

  So I can't get the corresponding value to apply a background color
- I have the same problem when clicking the element

My question is how to get the identifier for the selected element (circle shape in my case).

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `datum` is generating a path from each data item but throwing away the rest of it, including the properties. If you want to keep the properties, nest the object that it generates:

```
  .datum(function(d) {
    return {
       circle: circle
         .origin(origin({d: d}))
         .angle(radius({d: d}))(),
       d: d
    };
  })
```

And then the rest of your calls will follow: like

`.attr('d', function(d) { return path(d.circle); })`

And

```
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return color(d.d.year);
  })
```